# Phaser scenes don't load

Tags: javascript, html, loading, phaser-framework

in browser i see only black canvas and i define 2 scenes but I dunno why i see no text someone help pls
game.js

```
window.onload=function(){
    var game = new Phaser.Game();
    var config = {
        width: 800,
        height: 500,
        backgroundcColor: 0xffffff,
        scene: [Scene1, Scene2]
    }
    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
}
```

**Scene1.js**

```
class Scene1 extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor(){
        super("Scene1");
    }
    create(){
        this.add.text(20,20,"Loading game", {font:"25px Arial", fill:"yellow"});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some possible issues:

- remove the first line `var game = new Phaser.Game();` from the `onload` function. Since at the end you are creating it again, this time with the config object *(and each call create a new canvas / phaser app)*.
- Are you loading `Scene1` and `Scene2`, you have to load both if you reference the in the `config` if not it will cause an error an the execution stops *(Even if you are only using one)*.

If all this does solve the problem, check the browser console for errors, since any error in the code will/can stop the correct application flow.

**Here you can see, that your code works basiclly:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

class Scene1 extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor(){
        super("Scene1");
    }
    create(){
        this.add.text(20,20,"Loading game", {font:"25px Arial", fill:"yellow"});
    }
}

window.onload = function(){
    // remove this line it is not needed
    //var game = new Phaser.Game();
    var config = {
        width: 800,
        height: 500,
        backgroundcColor: 0xffffff,
        // Remove Scene2 if it is not loaded
        //scene: [Scene1, Scene2]                
        scene: [Scene1]
    }
    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

Comment: i got  some errors from 10:1 it's that preload function, sry but im still newbie`preload()
{
    this.sceneFile('Scene1', "../Scene1.js");}
create()
{
    this.scene.start('Scene1');
}
upload()
{

}`

Comment: @PLayPool these could be old error messages, or from the Scene2, since in your cod you are not using `preload`. My tipp for you is checkout this official tutorial https://phaser.io/tutorials/making-your-first-phaser-3-game (it's abit lame and old fashion, but shows the basics) and you can checkout all [this official examples page](https://phaser.io/examples) they show almost everything you can do with phaser. And for details on changing scenes check out this example https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/scenes/change-scene-from-create-es6

Comment: @PLayPool of you use the browser on the url of you Webserver it should work(as long as the files you reference are all on the same server/folder/subfolder). if you want to use phaser without hassel you could use the free version for thos editor https://phasereditor2d.com/ it is easy to setup and has even a graphical interface.